# What is missing in this Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm learning Cypher and I created a 'Crime investigation' project on `Neo4j`.

I'm trying to return as an output the parent that only has **two** sons/daughters in total and each member of the family must have committed a crime.
So, in order to get this in the graph, I executed this query:

```
match(:Crime)<-[:PARTY_TO]-(p:Person)-[:FAMILY_REL]->(s:Person)-[:PARTY_TO]->(:Crime)
where size((p)-[:FAMILY_REL]->())=2
return p, s
```

`FAMILY_REL` relation shows the sons the `Person` (`p`) and `PARTY_TO` relation shows the `Crime` nodes a `Person` have committed.

The previous query it's not working as it should. It shows parents with more than two sons and also sons that have just one son.

What is wrong with the logic of the query?

Answer (score 1):

`SIZE((p)-[:FAMILY_REL]->())` counts *all* children of `p`, including ones who had committed no crimes.

This query should work better, as it only counts children who are criminals:

```
MATCH (:Crime)<-[:PARTY_TO]-(p:Person)-[:FAMILY_REL]->(s:Person)-[:PARTY_TO]->(:Crime)
WITH p, COLLECT(s) AS badKids
WHERE SIZE(badKids) = 2
RETURN p, badKids
```